# Bash, insert last used argument of current command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, keyboard-shortcuts, arguments

I'm aware that you can recall the last argument of the previous command with `!$` and also cycle through previous arguments with `ALT + .` but can you recall the last argument used for the current command that is being used?

e.g,

```
root@chip:/# echo peckahs
root@chip:/# *_stuffthatdoesntmatter_*
root@chip:/# *_stuffthatdoesntmatter_*
root@chip:/# *_stuffthatdoesntmatter_*
root@chip:/# echo peckahs < used key shortcut to recall 'peckahs' the last used argument for echo
```

Comment: In short: I don't think so.

Comment: if the question isn't restricted too keybinds, `echo foo{,}` would print foo twice.

Comment: @llua I think Hauke Laging's edit to my question confused you, the last command would be `echo peckhas` not `echo peckahs peckahs`
After I type `echo` I want to use a shortcut to insert the last argument used for `echo` which would result in `echo peckahs`

Comment: I believe you would need to write a completion function that inspected history. Vague workarounds are to use `reverse-history-search` (`^R`), or `dynamic-complete-history` (`Esc ^I`) which completes previously used words, but independent of the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash you can do nearly what you're asking for like this:

```
echo !echo:$
```

So when you do

```
echo This is fun
ls
echo !echo:$
```

the last line outputs `fun`. `*` instead of `$` produces all the arguments to the matching command; so

```
echo This is fun
ls
echo !echo:*
```

outputs `This is fun` again; but you might as well just do

```
!echo
```

in this case.

This isn't limited to repeating a command's arguments with the same command:

```
printf !echo:*
```

See [the bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) for details. You could even combine this with the `histverify` shell option to give you a chance to check the command before it's executed, which gets you close to keyboard-interactive history-based completion.

History expansions can be used anywhere; so for example

```
lastechoargs="!echo:*"
```

stored all the arguments to the last `echo` command in the `lastechoargs` variable.

This works for complete commands too; say for example you've worked out a complex `git` command, and you want to save it in a file:

```
echo !git > mygitcommand
```

Or you want to archive some directories, but you decide to delete a couple of files first:

```
ls dir1 dir2
rm dir2/somefile
tar cpzf archive.tar.gz !ls:*
```

Answer (score 0):

If your bash in emacs-mode you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> (delete last word) then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> (input deleted string)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In any POSIX shell you can do...

```
set -o vi
^[[num]-#^[[num]_
```

...where `^[` represents the `ESC` key and `[num]` represents an optional parameter for `n`th history command counting backwards from the current one and `n`th argument in the previous command counting backwards from the last respectively. Depending on your keyboard config you may be able to use CTRL plus the combination key instead.

The sequence calls up the numbered command, prepends a `#` comment to it, and stores it back in the shell history as the most previous command. Then the `^[_` shortcut calls up the last arg in the last command.

`bash` also saves the last arg by default in the shell parameter `$_` so after doing the first part you could just expand the last arg in that way as well.